# Partially closed bosonic strings and freely moving D-branes

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions, branes

For closed bosonic strings, the embedding coordinates must satisfy
$$X^\mu(\tau,\sigma+2\pi)=X^\mu(\tau,\sigma)$$
for $\mu=0,1,\dots,D-1$. On the other hand, for open N-N bosonic strings, the embedding coordinates must satisfy
$$\partial_\sigma X^\mu(\tau,0)=\partial_\sigma X^\mu(\tau,2\pi)=0$$
for all $\mu$. Note that I consider an open string of length $2\pi$, so not the usual convention. This is convenient for the following.

Now let us consider the intermediate case
\begin{align}
\partial_\sigma X^a(\tau,0)=\partial_\sigma X^a(\tau,2\pi)=0&,\qquad a=0,1,\dots,p,\\
X^m(\tau,\sigma+2\pi)=X^m(\tau,\sigma),&\qquad m=p+1,\dots,D-1.
\end{align}
This means that the string is "closed" in some directions and open with Neumann boundary conditions in the other directions.

Let us consider the case $D=4$ and $p=2$ as an illustration. In this case, the strings propagates in three-dimensional space, its endpoints can move arbitrarily in the $X^1$ and $X^2$-directions (altouhg at the speed of light, as imposed by Neumann boundary conditions). In the $X^3$-direction however, the endpoints of the string always have to lie on at the same place, but they can move arbitrarily as long as it is satisfied. In summary, this a **N-N string whose endpoints are stuck in the same freely moving $X^1X^2$-plane.**

For general $D$ and $p$, we get a N-N string propagating in $(D-1)$-dimensional space whose endpoints are stuck in the same freely moving $X^1\cdots X^p$-hyperplane ($p$-dimensional). So we recover a kind "freely moving" Dirichlet boundary conditions without making reference to them in the first place. We get a **string with its endpoints stuck on a freely moving D$p$-brane**.

Does it make sense ?
What are in the implications of that when we quantize ?
Does it has any interest ?

Comment: It does not make sense to say that the field component you choose to look at changes the topology of the worldsheet. That needs to come first. Said another way, there is no action you can write down which enforces the conditions you wrote for $X^a$ and $X^m$. The closest thing I can think of is two open strings joining to become a closed string.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this doesn't change the topology depending of the components. It is an open string but with endpoints behaving in a special way, so for me its is the worldsheet of an open string with an unusual embedding.

Comment: If it's an open string then $X^m$ needs to satisfy a boundary condition which makes the action stationary. $X^m(\tau, \sigma + 2\pi) = X^m(\tau, \sigma)$ is not one of them.

Comment: I made an edit so there no contradiction between the positions of the endpoints, they now all are at $\sigma=0$ and $\sigma=2\pi$. So if I am not mistaken, the action is minimized for this configuration. Isn't it ?

Comment: No, the boundary term $\partial_\sigma X^\mu \delta X_\mu$ will be non-zero because of the $m$ components.

Comment: Once again, I apologize, but could detail why is that ? The situation for the $m$ coordinates seems to be the same than for the closed string, for which this term vanishes. No?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133166/discussion-between-xpsf-and-connor-behan).